# wdt resets on sending REST API subscribe request to PubNub, via esp8266

Tags: rest, pubnub, nodemcu, watchdog, arduino-esp8266

I am using [this](https://github.com/suryasundarraj/pubnub-esp8266-rest-api) code to connect NodeMCU esp8266 with PubNub. Publish works fine but subscribe is partially works for a while and then causes the controller to reset. The code properly follows the subscribe message time stamps mechanism.  While observing at Subscribe code, three steps are done in a loop;

```
//1. connecting to pubsub.pubnub.com
if (!client.connect(host, 80))
  {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }

//2. making and sending the GET request to subscribe
  url = "/subscribe/";
  url += subKey;
  url += "/";
  url += channel;
  url += "/0/";
  url += timeToken;
  //Serial.println(url);

  client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");             
  delay(10);

//3. finally listening the received msg response
  while (client.available())
  {
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    if (line.endsWith("]"))
    {
      Serial.println(line);
      json_handler(string_parser(line)); // handling the received msg
    }
  }
```

First step is causing the controller to reset (soft wdt resets),

```
Soft WDT reset

ctx: cont 
sp: 3ffef920 end: 3ffefcb0 offset: 01b0

>>>stack>>>
3ffefad0:  00000000 3ffefff8 3ffefff8 40204083  
3ffefae0:  402017b8 00000000 3ffefff8 40204083  
3ffefaf0:  00000000 3ffefff8 00000000 40202152  
3ffefb00:  001e8480 3ffe0001 3ffefd38 40202152  
3ffefb10:  00000000 00000040 00000000 00000000
```

I observed this by putting the first step (connecting to host), from void loop() to setup(), and I receive initial GET response as [[],"14970123776801072"], but after that, the connection is closed in step 2, so I will not receive any further messages from my subscribed channel. I tried to NOT close the connection at step 2 and it seems to work well, but with delays and sometimes receiving same message twice. I know this is not the ideal way of doing it. So my question is: Do we need to continuously make new connection and sent the GET request to receive messages from our channel and close the connection ? if yes, than what is actually causing the controller to reset ?

or is there any way of sending subscribe GET request once and then always wait for received messages ?